# Pull daily data into a report that stores all daily data for the month

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to setup something using Power Query to pull and insert values from the daily report into the correct location on the monthly report. I have got it set to pull and place the data in correct location based on the date. The problem I am running into is when I generate a new daily report it will put the new data where it is supposed to go by date, but since the new report overwrites the previous report my data from the day before is lost.

I am very new to using Power Query so my knowledge of what it can and can't do is very limited. Any recommendations on how to fix in place data from previous reports would be appreciated.

Comment: Powerquery cannot store data. You would need to create a cumulative database by storing historical data somewhere after each day's refresh, or perhaps you might save daily files in a single directory that you can then read and combine later.  Please do not create multiple questions with the same issue